# KnpPaginatorBundle 2.3 set parameter don't transform object

Tags: symfony

I try to use last version af knp_paginator with symfony 2.2.1

My query is:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('TemplateDefaultBundle:Member')->createQueryBuilder('m');

$query = $qb->select('m, p.id')
            ->join('m.photos', 'p' )
            ->where('m.status = 1')
            ->where('m.game = :game')
            ->andWhere('m.status = 1')
            ->setParameter('game', $this->game);
```

where `this->game` is the good object.

It works:

```
$query->getQuery()->execute();
```

And it **doesn't work**:

```
$pagination->paginate( $query->getQuery(), $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), 6 );
```

And give in the profiler i have

```
WHERE m0_.game_id = 'Object(Template\\DefaultBundle\\Entity\\Game)' AND m0_.status = 1
```

My composer.json:

```
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",...
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.3",
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not working"?

Comment: But do you get an error? What is the error message?

Comment: No error message but the generate query containt `WHERE m0_.game_id = 'Object(Template\\DefaultBundle\\Entity\\Game)'` instead of `WHERE m0_.game_id = 1 ` like with  `->execute()` so i have no result

Comment: What if you replace `setParameter('game', $this->game)` with `setParameter('game', $this->game->getId())`?

Comment: That's it! Thanks... How can i validate a comment?

Comment: You can't, it needs to be posted as an answer! :)

Comment: So please post it as an answer! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you are passing the object `game` instead of its `id`.
To get the result you want to have, replace `setParameter('game', $this->game)` with `setParameter('game', $this->game->getId())`.

So your query becomes:

```
$query = $qb->select('m, p.id')
        ->join('m.photos', 'p' )
        ->where('m.status = 1')
        ->where('m.game = :game')
        ->andWhere('m.status = 1')
        ->setParameter('game', $this->game->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ->getId() workaround currently this is possible to use next combination of paginator packages:

```
"knplabs/knp-components": "1.2.1",
"knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "~2.3"
```